# Python - receive through UDP

Tags: python, networking, udp

I am an engineer with little programming knowledge. Actually I am trying to program a device which should be controlled through our machine software.

The device has been plugged into our machine computer directly with a LAN cable and has a specific IP adress. I can open the interface when I type the IP adress in the browser.

For my program I am writing a code where data frames are send from the computer to the device. The data frames contain a hex code which are basically interpreted as commands like enable xy by the device.

The device also sends data frames which contain for example states and values which the machine computer has to receive.

In my code I open two sockets:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client .sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #IP and PORT of the device
server.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
data, addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
```

**My first problem** is that server.bind doesnt work if I am typing the IP adress of the device and I get this error:

> WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context.

**My second problem** is that whenever I am executing server.recvfrom my program is beeing catched like in a loop and doesnt continue. Maybe the computer doesnt receive any data and recvfrom only quits if it received data. Is that possible? How can I achieve a timeout for recvfrom for example that it quits after 5 seconds if it doesnt receive any data?

Comment: (1) You can't bind the second socket to the device's IP addess. It's nonsense. You can't bind a socket to a non-local address. (2) You don't need a second socket. The first socket is quite capable of receiving the reply. And you haven't enabled the conditions necessary for both sockets to share the same port. But it's unnecessary.

Comment: It's hard to see how (2) can possibly arise. If the bind fails the program should abort.

Comment: What can I do to solve this? Do I have to delete the second socket and bind the first socket to the local IP adress of my network card?

Comment: Delete the second socket. and send and receive with the first You probably don't really need to bind the other socket at all. The device should reply to from whence the datagram came.

Comment: If I dont use bind how would my program know which device in the network it has to listen to for receiving the data?

Comment: Your code first sends and then receives. The peer should respond to the source IP:port of the incoming request datagram. Your program doesn't have to 'listen to' anything. It is *possible* that the device only responds to a fixed port, although you haven't said so, in which case of course you do have to bind to that port. But that doesn't constitute listening to a device, it constitiutes binding to a local port.